# vue3 update conditional provide

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a vue3/firestore app. I am trying to make 1 call to firestore to get the users notifications, its conditional if there is a user signed in or not:

```
let { documents: notifications } = user.value && user.value.displayName ? getCollection('profiles', null, user.value.displayName, 'notifications') : ref([])
    provide('notifications', notifications)
```

This works fine if the user is signed in. The problem is if there is no user and they sign in, the provider doesn't update, and you have to refresh the app to get it work.

Potential solutions would be to watch the user state change, and then update the provider:

```
      if (!_user) return
      notifications = getCollection('profiles', null, user.value.displayName, 'notifications').documents
    })
```

But that doesn't work. The other solution would be to make the call/injection in another component that is only there if there is a user. The issue with this is all of these components are siblings and you can not provide to a sibling ?

Answer (score 0):

Any data that you `provide` are not automatically converted to a reactive data - you need to [do it yourself](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html#working-with-reactivity)

1. `provide` a `ref` or `reactive` object that wraps the data retrieved from Firebase
2. Use [authentication state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) to update provided data